# How to resolve "Target [FooController] is not instantiable" in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a controller in Laravel 4 but I keep getting the error when navigating to /foo:

```
Target [FooController] is not instantiable
```

Following the documentation I've got the following in routes.php (as the only route to rule out others):

```
Route::controller('foo', 'FooController');
```

and my controller looks like:

```
class FooController extends BaseController {
     public function getIndex() {
         return 'bar';
     }
}
```

Have I missed a step somewhere? I can't see anything obvious that looks wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is that all your code?

Comment: have you tried running "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: and what is your foo controller file name?

Comment: Ah found my mistake. In the base controller I had a constructor method to setup some common variables, it seems you also need to call this in the child class. Odd?

Comment: Its not odd - if you create a __construct() in a child class - you should always call parent::__construct()

Comment: Sharing your BaseController's __construct can be helpful for us to understand the issue and write a better answer.

Comment: I created the construct in the base class, I didn't use it in the child class

Comment: Please post your **BaseController** here also

Answer (score 0):

I got struck in same scenario! I accidentally made my controller non instantiable by typing `#` instead of `$` as variable name prefix which commented the variable name and made my constructor private!

```
private #pageTitle;

function __construct(DesignationRepository $designation)
{
    $this->designation = $designation;
    $this->pageTitle = 'designations';
}
```

Comment: That answer is relying pretty much on assumptions. Should have rather been a comment I think.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat I tried to add it as comment. but the code snippet was poorly aligned in it.